# Preserving ratio of a SVG element inside preserveAspectRatio="none"

Tags: svg

I have a SVG element with `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` and `preserveAspectRatio="none"` resizes automatically with the window size.

However I'm trying to have a fixed-size and perfect circle inside it. Seems like the outermost `<svg>` element does not allow this. Any ideas?

[(jsFiddle here)](http://jsfiddle.net/CqJDU/)

[image]

```
<svg width="100%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     preserveAspectRatio="none">

    <!-- ... OTHER SVG ELEMENTS I HAVE -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10px" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio=none` tells the browser to not preserve the aspect ratio, so, have you tried setting it to anything else? See http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute for reference.

Comment: See my answer to this question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891277/programmatically-centering-svg-path/16921836#16921836

Answer (score 3):

If you want a perfect sized circle, then try something like this...

```
<svg width="100%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"   style="border: 1px solid #000">
    <!-- ... OTHER SVG ELEMENTS I HAVE -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40px" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

The preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" property means that the circle will expand to the maximum x and y sizes so that the graphic doesn't overflow the box.