# SVG Preserve Aspect Ratio in Android

Tags: android, html, svg, responsive-design

I am having issues of SVG Scaling on Android Phones.

Couple of parts of my website are based on having both width and height dimensions for SVGs embeded via `<img>` tag. 
All the browsers except **Android 4.1.2 Native Browser**(NOT CHROME),scale SVGs Properly and perfectly without distorting Aspect Ratio.

**Here is screenshot of how it appears on Firefox(and all the browsers)**
[image]

**Here is screenshot of how it appears on the Android 4.1.2 Native Browser.**
[image]

**Testing URL**
http://prashantsani.com/demos/svgIssue/

**I tried all below solutions but none of them worked.**

1. Setting width, height and view-box does not work. Also, preserveAspectRatio does not work either. `<svg width="443.5" height="100" viewBox="0 0 443.5 100"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">`
2. Wrapping up inside another SVG did not do the trick (Also, i don't want to center the image, rather need a way scale the image propotionately).
   [Programmatically centering svg path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891277/programmatically-centering-svg-path/16921836#16921836)
3. I Tried this : [SVG Resize Image out of aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522361/svg-resize-image-out-of-aspect-ratio) but it does not work either. The width and height is already set in integers and not % or px.

**Please read following before Answering:**

1. Since the layout demands both width and height at some places, I have to keep both at some places.
2. This issue ONLY happens in NATIVE BROWSER APP on Android 4.1.2{"Browser" App} 
   . It works brilliantly, as expected in Chrome and all other browsers on Android 4.1.2.
3. A fiddle or codepen will be helpful if you find a solution.
4. Not planning to use any image format other than SVG.
5. **Width and height and mentioned in % via css....and SVG has to scale accordingly.**

Thanks.

Comment: It's completely counter-intuitive, but I believe you specify the SVG's (and its internal elements') `width` and `height` attributes in pure pixels, then scale the object up or down with CSS from there. Something about px being arbitrary orienting points within SVG's rendering model.

Comment: I used width and height in px, did not make any difference. also i have used  viewBox  and preserveAspectRatio. did not work either.

Comment: It may, unfortunately, be a browser bug. [Android has notoriously poor SVG rendering](http://thatemil.com/blog/2014/04/06/intrinsic-sizing-of-svg-in-responsive-web-design/).

Answer (score 1):

As per [This Article](http://codeandlife.com/2014/12/28/fixing-android-browser-svg-scaling-with-max-height/), `max-height: 100%;` and/or `max-width: 100%` within a style attribute seem to be potential fixes.

In my own case however, I had only specified `width="32"` with a `viewBox="0 0 32 32"`, once I added `height="32"` I no longer had any issues. I was too used to the majority of browsers that compensate for such things.

Answer (score 0):

The [question you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522361/svg-resize-image-out-of-aspect-ratio) had some troubles when running so I modified with standard html attributes and worked. Tested on an Inco Sphere tablet.

```html
<image width="100%" height="100%" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Tux_chico.svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <image width="100" height="100" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Tux_chico.svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" />
  <!-- Image By Gonzalo Rivero (Own work) [GFDL (http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html) or CC BY-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)], via Wikimedia Commons -->
```

In case you want to run it directly in your device i made a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/javatlacati/rguuexLv/show/) too.